# writing output on file doesn't work in python

Tags: python

I have the code below to write out a list of N-grams in Python.

from nltk.util import ngrams

```
def word_grams(words, min=1, max=6):
    s = []
    for n in range(min, max):
        for ngram in ngrams(words, n):
            s.append(' '.join(str(i) for i in ngram))
    return s
email = open("output.txt", "r")
for line in email.readlines():
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
            for line in email:
                prnt = word_grams(email.split(' '))
                f.write("prnt")
email.close()
f.close()
```

when I print out the `word_grams` it prints out the files correctly but when it comes to writing the output into `files.txt` it doesn't work. The "file.txt" is empty.

So I guess the problem must be within these lines of codes:

```
for line in email.readlines():
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
            for line in email:
                prnt = word_grams(email.split(' '))
                f.write("prnt")
email.close()
f.close()
```

Comment: How does it "not work?"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the code runs correctly w/o any errors and the file.txt  is empty.

Comment: You are writing the string "prnt" to your file. What you really want is to write the variable `prnt`. Simply remove the quotation marks.

Comment: @adelrahimi add that *to the question* not as a comment.

Comment: After having a second look, your code does not make much sense. You are first iterating over lines in `email`, in the iteration, ou iterate over the lines again and inside that iteration split the source string into words. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @SvenFestersen Im trying to open output.txt as `email` and then look over its lines then apply `word_grams` functions to it finally write that to the `file.txt`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I edited the `"print"` problem but it doesn't work...I have also tried deleting first iteration of opening `email` (deleting line 10) but I got  AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute split

Answer (score 1):

1) the final `f.close()` does something else than what you want (f inside the loop is another object)

2) You name the file "file.txt" but want the output in "files.txt". Are you sure that you are looking in a correct file?

3) You are overwriting the file for each line in the email. Perhaps the `with` statement for "file.txt" should be outside the loop.

4) You are writing `"prnt"` instead of `prnt`

Something like this?

```
def word_grams(words, min=1, max=6):
    s = []
    for n in range(min, max):
        for ngram in ngrams(words, n):
            s.append(' '.join(str(i) for i in ngram))
    return s

with open("output.txt", "r") as email:
    with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        for line in email.readlines():
            prnt = word_grams(line.split(' '))
            for ngram in prnt:
                f.write(ngram)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish exactly, but it seems that you would like to apply the function `word_grams` to every word in the file "output.txt" and save the output to a file called "file.txt", probably one item per line.

With these assumptions, I would recommend to rewrite your iteration in this manner:

```
words = []
# load words from input
with open("output.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        words += line.strip().split(" ")
# generate and save output
grams = apply(word_grams, words)
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(grams))
```

However, this code assumes that the function `word_grams` is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your code in loop:

```
for line in email:
```

did not run!

Because after `email.readlines()`run,the variable `email` is empty.
You can do some test like fallows:

```
email = open("output.txt", "r")
for line in email.readlines():
    print '1'
    for line in email:
        print '2'
```

if you have 3 lines in your output.txt,after you run this test,you will get:

```
1
1
1
```

in the output.

And you can do a test like this:

```
email = open("output.txt", "r")
email.readlines()
```

you will see a list with the lines in your output.txt.

but when you run `email.readlines()`again,you will get an empty list!

so,there should be the problem.your variable `email` is empty in your second loop.